# Is .length an appropriate call to a JavaScript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

For some reason, I cannot get the length of an array (it is undefined if it's unpopulated, right?).

```
define(function() {
  'use strict';

  var self = {},
    events = {};

  self.publish = function publish(eventName, data) {
    var subscribers, x, length;

    if (events[eventName]) {
      return false;
    }

    subscribers = events[eventName];

    for (x = 0, length = subscribers.length || 0; x < length; x += 1) {
      subscribers[x](data);
    }

    return true;
  };

  self.subscribe = function subscribe(eventName, func) {
    if (!events[eventName]) {
      events[eventName] = [];
    }

    events[eventName].push(func);
  };
  return self;
});
```

JSLint says: "Expected ';' and instead saw ','."
Jasmine says "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Why isn't length set to 0? Have I misunderstood the syntax an operations here?

Comment: Shouldn't you change ```for (x = 0, subscribers.length || 0; x < length; x += 1) {``` to ```for (x = 0; subscribers.length == 0 || x < subscribers.length; x += 1) {```

Comment: Why do you think `subscribers` is an array? It seems to be `undefined`.

Comment: `it is undefined if it's unpopulated, right` no, it's zero. Makes sense - there are zero objects in the array, hence the length is zero.

Comment: In your method you check `events[eventName]` and drop out if it has a value. So in the next line, it means it doesn't have a value, so `subscribers` is likely `undefined` at that point.

Comment: `subscribers` will always be `undefined` with this code. Because you return `false` when `events[eventName]` is truthy

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a negation in the `publish` function:

```
self.publish = function publish(eventName, data) {
    var subscribers, x, length;

    if (events[eventName]) { // <= Here you exit if there are subscribers, and continue if there arent
      return false;
    }

    subscribers = events[eventName];  // So subscribers is guaranteed to be undefined

    // can't get length (or any property) of undefined
    for (x = 0, length = subscribers.length || 0; x < length; x += 1) {
...
```

This causes your tests to fail. This is the way to go:

```
self.publish = function publish(eventName, data) {
    // you can use const and let
    // you are storing subscribers in a variable anyway, so why not doing it
    // before the check?
    const subscribers = events[eventName];

    if (!subscribers) {
      return false;
    }

    // you don't need to cache length in a variable, iirc it only improves performance slightly on IE browsers
    // neither need you `|| 0`
    // there other ways iterating through an array, see for..of and Array.prototype.forEach
    for (let x = 0; x < subscribers.length; x++) {
      subscribers[x](data);
    }

    return true;
};
```

> it is undefined if it's unpopulated, right?

No, the length of an array is zero if its empty. You get an undefined when reading a missing property of an object, but the length of an array is always a number.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with this line:

```
for (x = 0, subscribers.length || 0; x < length; x += 1) {
```

you defined the variable "length" but never initialized / assigned data to it.

In detail:

```
subscribers.length || 0
```

Whats this supposed to do?

```
x < length

x < length or x < subscribers.length?
```

Comment: I forgot to add the assignment. The response is still ' length undefined'

Comment: @KenIngram how did you modify it? Are you sure `events[eventName]`contains an array?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the code worked fine when I fixed the typo.

```
if (events[eventName]) {
```

is supposed to be

```
if (!events[eventName]) {
```

Everything worked as intended after that correction.
My debugging issues are always something stupidly minor

Answer (score -1):

like Don Bhrayan Singh said

your code should be

```
for (var x = 0, length = subscribers.length || 0; x < length; x += 1) {
  subscribers[x](data);
}
```

your previous code will run like this

```
// x = 0,           0           ; x < undefined; x += 1
for (x = 0, subscribers.length || 0; x < length; x += 1)     {
  subscribers[x](data);
}
```

Comment: `x = 0,           True           ; x < undefined; x += 1` what is that "True" there? It's completely incorrect whatever it is - the result of `subscribers.length || 0` will always be equal to the current length (in case the length is `0` it will proceed with the OR and still return `0`). However, that expression will be assigned to `x` since the comma operator is present. What would _actually_ happen is `x = subscribers.length; x < undefined; x += 1` and the check will always be `false`, because `undefined` is never going to be more than any number.

Comment: you are right to say that the expression will evaluate to 0. but how can it be assigned to x? I thought js will simply evaluate the expression.